# Wireless network adapter problems with Realtek

Tags: realtek-wireless

I've been scouring the internet and have viewed a couple different posts on this site and have done everything and anything I can to get this network adapter to work. When I click on the wireless, it says "no network devices detected". I ran the `lsusb` command and the two that m going to assume are the network adapter come back with:

```
bus 001 device 004: ID 0bda:b001 realtek semiconductor corp.
bus 001 device 005: ID 0bda:0177 realtek semiconductor corp.
```

There is absolutely no way i can plug this in via cat-5 line since there is no port on this netbook in trying to install ubuntu onto.

When I run `lspci | grep -i wireless`, it just goes down one line and I receive nothing else there.

`nm-tool` returns: `State: disconnected`

```
nmcli nm
RUNNING         STATE           WIFI-HARDWARE   WIFI       WWAN-HARDWARE   WWAN      
running         disconnected    enabled         enabled    enabled         disabled
```

```
sudo rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
iwconfig
lo    no wireless extensions.
```

`lspci -v` (there are quite a few things here but the Realtek network controller says this):

```
01:00.0 network controller: realtek semiconductor co., ltd device b723
subsystem: hewlett-packard company device 2231
flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, irq 106
i/o ports at 1000 {size=256}
memory at 90400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) {size=16k}
capabilities: <access denied>
kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
kernel modules: rtl8723be
```

I don't know what other information you would need but as I said I can't hook it up via an ethernet cable since there is no port on the netbook for one. I need to be able to get the files i need and put them onto an sd card and transfer them to the netbook to install them that way.

Comment: also sorry for my lack of structure... i tried hitting return/enter to go down a line but it didnt work the way i was expecting it to... it was all neat and pretty looking til i looked at the bottom and posted :( i appologize

Comment: ty for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating the driver fixed this issue for me.

Go to

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new/

And download the file to your sd card. Transfer file to whatever directory you like.

```
cd (directory you chose to copy to)
```

Then

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

Then run

```
make
```

Then

```
sudo make install
```

Lastly reboot your computer, the issue should be resolved

Comment: ok i downloaded that entire thing... i put the rtl8723be folder onto my desktop and cd /home/bob/Desktop i do the next thing you say "make" it says no targets specified and no makefile found. stop. so i typed make rtl8723be and it came back with make: warning: file 'rtl8723be' has modification time 7.7e+07 s in the future

Comment: make: nothing to be done with rtl8723be

Comment: make: warning: clock skew detected. your build may be incomplete

Comment: I forgot to add a cd. You should cd into /home/bob/Desktop/rtlwifi_new I will add the step to answer

Comment: If you renamed the Realtek folder you downloaded, you would cd into that, otherwise the path I gave you above should work

Comment: ok that seems to be working thank you. im not stupid when it comes to ubuntu but some of the terminal stuff gets a little ehh when its types wrong or if confused about a step lol but i do REALLY appreciate this so much man thank you. i will put this as the answer right now.. its actually doing something this time :D so happy i can give this computer back to the person lol

Comment: and to update this... it works ur a lifesaver

Comment: Glad to help, everyone learns their own way